# Get friendly URL and query database

Tags: .htaccess, web, webserver

I need to know **what web server and server side framework** will let me achieve the following:

I don't know is there is a technical name for this technique. So basically want to get any url in my domain and use it to query a database.

So for example, if I navigate to http://example.com/jack.htm, I want to do "select * from users where name like %jack%"

and then I want to return in the web page something like:

Our user's named Jack:

- Jack Martins age 26
- Jack Johnson age 32
  etc..

Obviously we have a sql database with all user's names and age. Also jack.htm does not exist as a htm document in my web server, I need to generate it on the fly but not actually keep it forever.

Comment: basically, any web framework will work, eg flask in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webserver needs to rewrite the URL and turn the part before ".htm" into a parameter for an existing page that uses this parameter to query the database.

Eg. apache config

```
RewriteRule /\(.*\)\.htm$  /querydb.php?$1
```

I'v no experience with .htaccess, but something like:

```
RewriteRule ^\(.*\)\.htm$  /querydb.php?$1
```

Watch out for SQL injection inside querydb.php

jack.htm will never need to exist, and if it does, it won't be used.

Comment: I want to avoid anyone knowing about the existance of querydb.php. If I use this way, will the URL in the user's browser change? Will the user be able to find about querydb.php using devtools, inspectors. etc? I don't want anyone manually calling querydb.php?$1, querydb.php?$2, etc querydb.php should only be accesed from server's localhost

Comment: No, keep the "redirect" internal, don't send the user the modified URL.  You can easily block direct requests for querydb.php.